# Does Elasticsearch 2.4 support .gte function?

Tags: elasticsearch

Alternative for this as i am not getting for gte() as i am migrating elastic search from 1.4 to 2.4?

```
 Double price;     
 NotFilterBuilder excMaxPriceFilter = FilterBuilders.notFilter(FilterBuilders.rangeFilter("exclude_max_price").gte(price));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite your code to this:

```
BoolQueryBuilder excMaxPriceFilter = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
    .mustNot(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("exclude_max_price").gte(price));
```